# Bullseye-shaped interference pattern in seminar-room chair

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, physics

During a break n a seminar today, I noticed that the chairs in front of me all had slightly transparent black mesh fabric. The backs of the chairs were in the shape of a hyperbolic paraboloid. The fabric covering it had two layers a couple of centimeters apart (it was just a fabric sheath over a frame), and the mesh was a hexagonal tiling with hole size approximately equal to thread size, both small.

I noticed that the interference between the two meshes made a bullseye pattern. The circles in the bullseye moved inwards or outwards as I moved my head, but the center of the bullseye seemed to be constantly at the critical point of the hyperbolic paraboloid (although I couldn't move my head much from side to side).

Why did this shape appear?

Comment: You may be referring to a Moire pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moire_pattern

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm referring to. I know that interference patterns occur(although the article really helped me understand it better), but my question is, why did it have that particular shape?

Comment: @Jeremy, it is amazing that you got it from just the description.

Comment: I honestly couldn't quite figure out what picture you have in mind. I guess it is a bit late to ask whether you happened to take a photo of the pattern?

Comment: @WillieWong: I didn't, but they are in the math seminar room at UPenn in the DRL (I think 4C8 or 4C28), in case anyone one here has time, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen the chairs in question, so below is just pure speculation. I suspect, but am not sure, that what you saw was a combination of two effects caused by the chair frame.

1. Because the chair frame is a hyperbolic paraboloid, from where you sit the pattern of "holes" in the fabric appears effectively *aperiodic* while roughly uniformly distributed.
2. Because the chair frame has a physical dimension, one layer of the chair fabric is further away from you then the other. From where you sit the layer that is further away from you appears to be "smaller".

Apparently if you start with an aperiodic screen pattern $A$ and produce a Moiré pattern based on $A$ and a rotation and/or rescaling $A'$, you tend to observe circular patterns. See figures 2.1c and 2.1e [here](http://lspwww.epfl.ch/books/moire/figs1II.html#c). In general, I think you may be able to find an answer to your question in [this book](http://lspwww.epfl.ch/books/moire/index.html).

**update:** Links refer to  *The Theory of the Moiré Phenomenon* by Isaac Amidror. Original published in paperback in 2000 (hardcover earlier) and then expanded to two volumes in 2007/2009: [volume I](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789401142052) and [volume II](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402054570).

Comment: Thanks! Looking back, it probably just looked like it was centered at the critical point since I was directly behind it. I've googled "black mesh office chair" and saw a lot of moire patterns, by the way.

Comment: @WillieWong [Are meaningless link titles like “Source” sub-optimal, leaving the answer unrepairable if a link rots/breaks?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1356/12102) If those links were to pages with names that were moved, we might be able to track them down if we had more than "here" and "this book" to go on. Now I'm *extremely* curious to see what was there!

Comment: The links were to _The Theory of the Moiré Phenomenon_
by
Isaac Amidror. There are now two volumes (a sequel has been published). @uhoh

Comment: @WillieWong thanks! I've made an attempt to update the post accordingly. I will definitely go check these out since some may apply to the Moire patterns I see when doing [this stuff](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619).